# Nancyfx: Defining the servername instead of localhost

Tags: c#, webserver, localhost, nancy

Using Nancyfx in C# to develop the REST Server, however its working for localhost only with different ports. 
I want to use it from other PCs in same network, so tried to change localhost to `<systemname>` but not working.

Comment: what's the exception you're getting?

Comment: No exceptions its running, but unable to access it through the browser.

Comment: Just covering the bases. Do you have a hole in your firewall?

Comment: No firewall restrictions